# How to filter a signal?

Tags: matlab, filter

I need to filter a time domain simple signal through a analog low pass filter which i have designed. I need the output signal in time domain.

```
%LPF
order=3;

ripple = 1; %pass band ripple
f_c= 22e6;

[num1, den1] = cheby1(order, ripple, 2*pi*1.10*f_c, 'low', 's');

%Create input signal

Fs=200e6;

Ts=1/Fs;

NFFT=2^12;

Runtime=(NFFT-1)*Ts;

t=0:Ts:Runtime

a_in=1;

phase_in=0;

y_in=a_in*sin(2*pi*fin*t+phase_in);  % 4096 points
```

I need the output signal `y_out` in time domain of 4096 points. What do I need to do?

Comment: its an anolog filter.. use 'freqs' function

Comment: My fault, skipped the 's', you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use the `filter()` function of the signal processing toolbox. It takes the filter coefficients and the signal to be filtered as arguments:

```
y = filter(b,a,x)
```

where `b` are the numerator coeffiecients, `a` is the denominator and `x` the signal to be filtered. The output vector has usually the same size as the input, so since your input is 4096 samples, also your output will be 4096 samples. More info [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html).

So in your case:

```
y_out = filter(num1, den1, y_in)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply.
I had already tried that.. but i get NaN values.

Comment: I also though i could take the impulse response of the filter :

sys=tf(num1,den1);
ss=impulse(sys);
ss=ss/max(ss);

I am not sure how to do the convolution then,, i am also not sure the results after that... and how to adjust the number of points ?

Comment: f_in=20e6... input frequency

Comment: hey,, i tried the zpk method .. its still the same

[z,p,k] = cheby1(order, ripple, 2*pi*1.10*f_c, 'low', 's');
[n d]=zp2tf(z,p,k);

y_out=filter(n,d,y_in);

other ideas?

Comment: `cheby1(...,'s')` gives you an analog filter. To filter a digital signal you need a digital filter, therefore you can/need to convert the analog filter to a digital one using the `bilinear` Matlab function (in your case: `[z,p,k]=bilinear(z,p,k,Fs); [b,a]=zp2tf(z,p,k); filter(b,a,y_in)`). After that also the filter function should work as expected. Analog filters are usually implemented in hardware or simulated in something like NI Multisim.

Comment: Hey.. its still does not work ..

Check it out ...for f_in of 175 MHz.. the o/p is not attenuated.. but somehow is attenuated for 40 or so MHz...  the f_corner r is 22 MHz

%LPF
order=3;
ripple = 1; %pass band ripple
f_c= 22e6;
[z,p,k] = cheby1(order, ripple, 2*pi*1.10*f_c, 'low', 's');


%Create input signal
Fs=200e6;
Ts=1/Fs;
NFFT=2^14;
Runtime=(NFFT-1)*Ts;
t=0:Ts:Runtime;
a_in=1;
phase_in=0;
fin=175e6;
y_in=a_in*sin(2*pi*fin*t+phase_in);  % 4096 points

% filter signal

[z,p,k]=bilinear(z,p,k,Fs); 
[b,a]=zp2tf(z,p,k); 
y_out=filter(b,a,y_in);
plot(t,[y_in; y_out])

Comment: You seem to keep randomly changing your parameters, which makes no sense. I assume you want to suppress the input. So do it like this:
`ripple=1; 
order=3;
f_c=22e6;
[z,p,k]=cheby1(order,ripple,2*pi*f_c,'s');
[b,a]=zp2tf(z,p,k);
Fs=250e6;
Ts=1/Fs; 
NFFT=2^12; % for 4096 points 
Runtime=(NFFT-1)*Ts; 
t=0:Ts:Runtime; 
a_in=1; 
phase_in=0; 
fin=100e6;
y_in=a_in*sin(2*pi*fin*t+phase_in); 
[z,p,k]=bilinear(z,p,k,Fs); 
[b,a]=zp2tf(z,p,k); 
y_out=filter(b,a,y_in); 
plot(t,y_in, t,y_out)` You will see that the y_in will be suppressed. You should probably read some tutorial/book.

Comment: i am sorry for bothering you.. but even using your code .. the issue persists..

u can yourself check it..

if--- f_in=110 MHz.. the attenuation is good
but if f_in=210 MHz ... the attenuation is less than that at 110 MHz input..

Comment: Thanks...

Let me explain the big picture..

My input is any frequency from 0 to 200 MHz 
My filter is also designed for all values 0 to 200 MHz, with corner at 22 MHz...

I need to apply the any input from the  input band.. onto the filter.. and then get the attenuated output..  ..

that output then goes into the ADC (fft) runing at fs = 200 MHz.

I know the input can not be greater than 100 MHz  because it will alias back... 
at the end i want to see the attenuated alias of say ip 190 MHz at 10 MHz.

Comment: Yes.. Thanks.. Exactly...

I just need to downsample it back to 200MHz before the ADC .

Comment: Ok, so you want to simulate this analog filter? But in simulation you still need for it to work a sufficiently high Fs, and the Fs of 200MHz of the ADC does not really appy to the original signal. So I suggest you use Fs>=400MHz for this simulation, so you can use f_in up to 200Mhz. After the analog filter your signal will have max(f) of about 22MHz (higher will be suppressed due to filter), so Fs=200MHz of ADC will be ok. Yes, I guess you can downsample to simulate the undersampling.